# TestNG Factory and @BeforeClass or @BeforeSuite used with DataProvider

Tags: java, testng

when using constructor Factory together with DataProvider, the dataprovider is always run before @BeforeSuite.

Anybody know what is going on ? It is quite useless because I can't imagine that I would initialize stuff in one of @DataProviders...

Also if I I use a DataProvider that makes constructor of @Factory run 2 times, then the test class is run 2 times with @BeforeClass and then it runs again without @BeforeClass.. The third cycle shouldn't exist, because DataProvider returns only 2 values...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is by design like this. You just need to avoid using anything that is being initialized in @BeforeSuite method in your DataProviders or initialize it statically.